# How to download Facebook page posts

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am an iOS developer and I am writing an app which needs to take statuses from my Facebook page and and display them in my app.

1. Does the Facebook API support that?
2. If it does, can anyone give a link for some tutorials or explain how can I make this?

I know that API supports an RSS feed but i don't found how to feed my statuses.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Facebook page, you can easily use the graph API to query for posts made by that page. For example, for Starbucks:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/Starbucks/posts
```

You can simply load this in your browser to see the format the data comes back in, and all that's needed to access this data is a simple HTTP request. You can replace `Starbucks` with your Page's ID or username to get your Page's posts. These come back in JSON, which should be fairly easy to handle on your end.

Comment: Can you tell how to gets posts on the Facebook page. After this info about page getting not posts or events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Facebook [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) allows you to access your profile and extract any information you'd like from it.